# Edeliver - Impossible to access on port 4000 after successful deploy

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, edeliver

I'm trying to deploy a simple phoenix app with **edeliver**. Yesterday after many struggle it worked. Anyway, today I worked on it a bit and tried to
release a new version:

```sh
mix edeliver build release --branch=production # looks fine
mix edeliver deploy release to production # looks fine
mix edeliver restart production # looks fine
```

If I run `ps aux` on my server I can see:

```
root     29773  0.0  0.0   7620   292 ?        S    08:58   0:00 /var/www/elixirhunt.prod/elixirhunt/erts-8.0/bin/epmd -daemon
root      3179  0.0  0.0   4328   356 ?        Ss   09:59   0:00 erl_child_setup 1024
root      3060  0.4  9.9 2228364 49992 pts/0   Ssl+ 09:59   0:03 /var/www/elixirhunt.prod/elixirhunt/erts-8.0/bin/beam -- -root /var/www/elixirhunt.prod/elixirhunt -progname var/www/eli
root      3059  0.0  0.1  14860   804 ?        S    09:59   0:00 /var/www/elixirhunt.prod/elixirhunt/erts-8.0/bin/run_erl -daemon /var/www/elixirhunt.prod/elixirhunt/tmp/erl_pipes/elixi
```

So the daemons are running. If I run `mix edeliver ping production` everything looks fine too.

When I try to reach my server with the right port configured in **prod.secret.exs**

```ruby
config :elixirhunt, Api.Endpoint,
  http: [port: 4000],
  url: [host: "www.elixirhunt.prod", port: 4000],
  cache_static_manifest: "priv/static/manifest.json",
  server: true
```

It doesn't work: http://46.101.2.126:4000/

(Yesterday it worked fine).

I checked if something is listening on the port 4000, but it seems not:

```
netstat -anp | grep ":4000 "

(void)
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved: `config :elixirhunt, Api.Endpoint,`was wrong, the namespace of my application is Elixirhunt.Endpoint.