# Edeliver Starting Phoenix/Elixir App on Random TCP Port

Tags: azure, deployment, elixir, phoenix-framework, edeliver

We are trying to deploy our Phoenix Web App to a Linux VM (*in our case on Azure*)
using [`edeliver`](https://github.com/edeliver/edeliver)
We have deployed a ["basic" Blog App](https://github.com/nelsonic/pxblog) to Azure using `edeliver` and *documented* the steps: 
https://github.com/dwyl/learn-microsoft-azure#part-2-deploying-your-application

*And* when we *manually* run the ("*real*") app: https://github.com/nelsonic/healthlocker 
on the instance using `MIX_ENV=prod mix phoenix.server` it runs fine!

When we deploy and run the app to the Azure instance using the following commands:

```
mix edeliver build release --verbose
mix edeliver deploy release to production
mix edeliver start production
```

We get a *positive* confirmation message:

```
EDELIVER HEALTHLOCKER WITH START COMMAND

-----> starting production servers

production node:

  user    : root
  host    : 51.140.86.5
  path    : /home/hladmin
  response: ok


START DONE!
```

However when we run `netstat -plnt` as suggested by [checking-running-services-on-linux](https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/checking-running-services-on-linux/)
we notice that `edeliver` is starting the Phoenix App on a ***random*** **TCP Port**:

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:29130         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3759/mdsd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:38863           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      56269/beam.smp
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:4369            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      32642/epmd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1557/sshd
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5432          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      16901/postgres
tcp6       0      0 :::4369                 :::*                    LISTEN      32642/epmd
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1557/sshd
```

In this case the app is running on PORT `38863`, even thought our [`prod.exs` config file has *hard coded* the PORT to `4000`](https://github.com/nelsonic/healthlocker/blob/809ecfb680df765e815841882462b0b3ac9da865/config/prod.exs#L15) ***and*** we have an Environment Variable to set it to `4000` in our [`.profile` file](https://github.com/dwyl/learn-phoenix-framework/blob/master/production-deployment.md#162-edit-your-profile-file-on-azure-instance-to-set-tcp-port-for-phoenix) as per the instructions (*just-in-case*).

So my *questions* are:

### Why is `edeliver` start the Phoenix App on a *Random* TCP PORT...?

*and*

### *How* do I get `edeliver` to boot the app on PORT `4000`?

Our [`.deliver/config`](https://github.com/nelsonic/healthlocker/blob/809ecfb680df765e815841882462b0b3ac9da865/.deliver/config) is on GitHub.

We have *attempted* to read the *logs* in `/home/{username}/{appname}/var/log` as per @dogbert's instructions in:
[How to View Production Logs in Phoenix Web Application Deployed using Edeliver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43996349/how-to-view-production-logs-in-phoenix-web-application-deployed-using-edeliver)
But *neither* `erlang.log.1` or `run_erl.log` made us any *wiser*... :-(

Any help *understanding* this would be *much* appreciated! (*Please & Thanks!*)

**Note**: Sadly, while this Q: [Edeliver - Impossible to access on port 4000 after successful deploy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39558709/edeliver-impossible-to-access-on-port-4000-after-successful-deploy) *sounds* similar, the solution does not work for us (*we tried*)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks to me like you didn't read the Phoenix documentation for deploying via releases. [Distillery](https://hexdocs.pm/distillery) also has documentation for this.

In a gist, this is what you need in your config:

```
config :healthlocker, Healthlocker.Endpoint
  server: true,
  root: ".",
  version: Mix.Project.config[:version]
```

Ensure those three config options are set in your prod `config.exs` file, and you should be good to go.

Comment: Worked! @bitwalker you _legend_! thanks for helping us with this! and thanks for distillery. :-)